# How to add a character in front of multiple words in linux

Tags: linux, bash

Here is a text file containing many words,each is separated by space breaks or line breaks.
Now I want to add a character,like "#" "$" "@" in front of each of them,
and I found doing this job one by one will take too much time,
are there any better ways,in bash?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using `sed`

```
sed -r 's/([^ ]+)/@\1/g' file
```

Or more concisely,

```
sed -r 's/[^ ]+/@&/g' file
```

---

Sample input

```
abc def pqr-stu xyz
```

Output

```
@abc @def @pqr-stu @xyz
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`, you could say:

```
sed 's/\b\w/#&/g' inputfile
```

This would append `#` before every word.

Comment: this will fail in case of `abc-def` which I think a single word and will result in `#abc-#def`. OP says words are separated only by space, breaks or line breaks.

Comment: in that event isn't it trivial to replace \w with \S

Comment: that change gives output `#abc#-#def`. I need to be `\S+`